# clearContent does not run onChange in Google Sheets script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have written a script to clear a range of cells `(B4:B8)` when a specified cell `(C1)` is changed. However, the cells are not cleared when I edit the specified cell. Here is the script:

```
function onChange() {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Quality Control').getRange('C1');
 ScriptApp.newTrigger("clearRange")
   .forSpreadsheet(sheet)
   .onChange()
   .create();
}

function clearRange() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Quality Control');
  sheet.getRange('B4:B8').clearContent();
}
```

The function `onChange` is set to run `onOpen` (trigger).

Any idea why this script isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

## Short answer

Instead of creating a trigger by code create it manually. Set your trigger to call the clearRange() directly.

## Explanation

The script in the question is not working because there is a bug but rather than fixing the bug could be better to set a trigger manually otherwise a new trigger will be created every time that the spreadsheet be opened.

To create a trigger manually, follow the instructions from https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually

> ### Managing triggers manually
>
> To manually create an installable trigger through a dialog in the
> script editor, follow these steps:
>
> 1. From the script editor, choose Resources > Current project's triggers.
> 2. Click the link that says: No triggers set up. Click here to add one now.
> 3. Under Run, select the name of function you want to trigger.
> 4. Under Events, select either Time-driven or the Google App that the script is bound to (for example, From spreadsheet).
> 5. Select and configure the type of trigger you want to create (for example, an Hour timer that runs Every hour or an On open trigger).
> 6. Optionally, click Notifications to configure how and when you will be contacted by email if your triggered function fails.
> 7. Click Save.

### Comments about the code on the question

`.forSpreadsheet(sheet)` requires that `sheet` be a spreadsheet object but your code assigns a range to the `sheet` variable.

From https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/spreadsheet-trigger-builder#onchange

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 ScriptApp.newTrigger("myFunction")
   .forSpreadsheet(sheet)
   .onChange()
   .create();
```

See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/troubleshooting to learn how to use the debugging tools on the Google Apps Script Editor

Comment: Thanks for your response, Rubén. I attempted to assign a range to the sheet variable because I would like the clearRange function to execute when a specified cell is changed. Is this possible using the onChange function? If not, what do you suggest?